# regex for formatting words

Tags: c#, regex

how can I format below string

**Address1=**+1234+block+of+XYZ+Street+**Address2=**+Santa+Fe+Springs+**State=**+California

to string

**Address1=**+1234+block+of+XYZ+Street+**&Address2=**+Santa+Fe+Springs+**&State=**+California

The below regex doesnt work properly.could someone fix this?

```
string inputString = "Address1=+1234+block+of+XYZ+Street+Address2=+Santa+Fe+Springs+State=+California";
string outString = Regex.Replace(inputString,@"([\s])([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(=)","&$1");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want to do is prefix "Address2" and "State" by an ampersand:

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, "(?=Address2=|State=)", "&");
```

Comment: What if someone lives on State St.? Might be better to match `State=` for the second case.

Comment: the only problem I have with this is sometime my inputs has address2.is there a w ay to escape case sesitivity?

Comment: @jball yes thats a valid scenario.

Comment: This is a clearer for the specific question, but it doesn't scale well if there are more keywords.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want this

```
Regex.Replace(inputString,@"\+([a-zA-Z0-9]+)=","+&$1=")
```

Or this if you want to allow any character other than + & = in keywords.

```
Regex.Replace(inputString,@"\+([^+&=]+)=","+&$1=")
```

Comment: @gnarf: + rather than * for sure, I'm less certain about allowing chars other than alpha and numbers as keywords.  Might be better, might not.  I'll make the + change

Comment: @gnarf: why % in [^+%=] did you mean & ?